# user log in on page reload in MEAN app using passport.js

Tags: passport.js, mean-stack

I'm using passportjs for authentication in my MEAN app.

I'm just confused about how can I identify that user is logged in or not on page refresh. Currently I'm storing user data in $rootScope, so it is working if I do not reload. But when I reload page $rootScope gets cleared so in this situation how can I get user information.

A cookie is set by passport, What is the purpose of that and can I use that cookie to authenticate, and if yes, how ?

Comment: How do you get user data to $rootScope in first place then?

Comment: when user first login then on success I save the user details into rootscope

Comment: So you use some /login route right? You can create route /user and use ajax to check if user is logged in.  if(req.user) res.json(req.user);

Comment: Or you could inject user object in head of the page and check if user exists after page load in angular

Comment: I'm not getting it, could you please elaborate with example or some link which I can refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a route `/user` and from angular check if a user is logged in

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res, next){
    if(req.user) return res.json(req.user);
    res.json({error: 'not logged in});
});
```

or inject user to page when you render it

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    res.render('index');
});
```

and in the view (i use handlebars)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

    {{#if user}}
      var user = {
        username: {{user.name}},
        email: {{user.email}}
      }
    {{/if}}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

and then in your controller check if the user object exists, inject $window as dependency

```
if($window.user) {
    $rootScope.user = $window.user;
}
```